# Function using vector index not value in internal data.frame with dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

**Problem:**

I have a function that uses an argument to index to an internal `data.frame`, but returns an integer. However when I run the function in `dplyr::mutate` to create a new variable based on another variable in a`data.frame`, I get an error:

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>   Evaluation error: duplicate subscripts for columns.
> ```

This appears to be caused by the internal indexing of the data frame using the index position of the variable, instead of its value.

How can I solve this?

**Example:**

In this function I need to index to an internal `data.frame` and use this in the calculation of the result. :unction and data:

```
toyfun <- function(thing1){

  thing2 <- data.frame(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0)
  thing2[, thing1] <- 1

  thing3 <- sum(thing2[1,]) + thing1

  return(thing3)
}


toydat <- tibble(thing1 = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2))
```

Function does as expected:

```
toyfun(thing1 = toydat$thing1[1])
#[1] 5
```

But if I want to calculate the function with each element of a variable in a `tibble` or `data.frame`, with `mutate`, it fails:

```
toydat %>% 
  mutate(thing4 = toyfun(thing1 = thing1))
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#  Evaluation error: duplicate subscripts for columns.
```

If we just use the first 4 rows (or fewer) of `toydat`, *and note that the internal `data.frame` in `toyfun` is 4 columns wide*, it works fine

```
toydat[1:4,] %>% 
  mutate(thing4 = toyfun(thing1 = thing1))
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   thing1 thing4
#    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1      4      5
# 2      3      4
# 3      2      3
# 4      1      2
```

But again, if we use 5 rows, so going over the index value of the internal `data.frame`, we fail again:

```
toydat[1:5,] %>% 
  mutate(thing4 = toyfun(thing1 = thing1))
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#   Evaluation error: duplicate subscripts for columns.
```

**Crux of the issue**

This result seems to illustrate that the problem is with this internal indexing using the index value from `thing1` rather than it's actual value. Which is weird, because as used in the 4-row example above, we can see that the returned values in thing4 are as they should be from using the values of `thing1` to calculate the result.

NB: The same problem doesn't occur with `sapply`:

```
sapply(toydat$thing1, toyfun)
# [1] 5 4 3 2 2 3
```

Any ideas on ways around this in the `dplyr` type framework so I can keep the work flow consistent?

Comment: The value of `thing1` is never `> ncol(thing2)` in the data here or above. But putting in if it is return NA and else do as above returns error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: duplicate subscripts for columns.
In addition: Warning message:
In if (thing1 > ncol(thing2)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `mutate` sends the entire column together to the function.

Let's debug the function

```
toyfun <- function(thing1){
   browser()
   thing2 <- data.frame(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0)
   thing2[,thing1] <- 1
   thing3 <- thing1 + 1
  return(thing3)
}
```

Now we run the `mutate` command

```
toydat %>% 
  mutate(thing4 = toyfun(thing1 = thing1))
#Called from: toyfun(thing1 = thing1)
#Browse[1]> thing1
#[1] 4 3 2 1 1 2
```

As there are duplicate entries of column 1 , it gives an error.

It is same as

```
df <- mtcars
df[, c(5, 5)] <- 1
```

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , c(1, 1), value = 1) : 
>     duplicate subscripts for columns

Now let's look at `sapply` call

```
sapply(toydat$thing1, toyfun)
#Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
#Browse[1]> thing1
#[1] 4
```

`sapply` passes the value one by one hence there is no error.

This is same as

```
df <- mtcars
df[, 5] <- 1
df[, 5] <- 1
```

which doesn't give any error.

To resolve the error we can use `unique` to get only `unique` entries of `thing1`

```
toyfun <- function(thing1){
  thing2 <- data.frame(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0)
  thing2[,unique(thing1)] <- 1
  thing3 <- thing1 + 1
  return(thing3)
}


toydat %>% 
    mutate(thing4 = toyfun(thing1 = thing1))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  thing1 thing4
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      4      5
#2      3      4
#3      2      3
#4      1      2
#5      1      2
#6      2      3
```

and this would also continue to work with `sapply`

```
sapply(toydat$thing1, toyfun)
#[1] 5 4 3 2 2 3
```

If you do not want to change the function, another option is to use `rowwise` which works same as `sapply` and sends each individual value one by one to the function

```
toydat %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(thing4 = toyfun(thing1 = thing1))

#Called from: toyfun(thing1 = thing1)
#Browse[1]> thing1
#[1] 4

toydat %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(thing4 = toyfun(thing1 = thing1))

#  thing1 thing4
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      4      5
#2      3      4
#3      2      3
#4      1      2
#5      1      2
#6      2      3
```

Hope this was clear and helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this expansive answer, it demonstrates the issue, but the answer isn't what I'm after - I don't want the unique values of `thing1`, in calculating the variables in `thing4` I want to use the equivalent variable in variable `thing1`, not all unique values in `thing1` in each calculation of `thing4`. I'll clarify the question further.

Comment: @Umaomamaomao hmmm...I am a little confused now. Did you check with `rowwise` ? It doesn't give any error for your new function at least.

Comment: Yep that's the solve. I'm baffled why that's necessary though - the manual states that `rowwise` is for working on list variables, but toydat$thing1 isn't a list...

Comment: for the same reason. It sends one value at a time in the function. So if you use `mutate` without `rowwise`, `toyfun` would be called only once whereas if you use `rowwise` it will be called `n()` times. (one for each value).

Comment: Yeah I thought that was the default behaviour in mutate anyway, but now that I think about it, most of the functions I'd be using are vectorised already...